# Tooltip DataGridCell with different text alignment

Tags: wpf, text-alignment

In

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
```

I set the WPF style for TextBlock's in the DataGridCell's of this column. E.g.
`<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>`
Now the tooltip of this cell gets the same centered text alignment but I want the
tooltip to have left text alignment.
The following does not work and I don't understand why not.
What should I do?

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ToolTip>
            <ToolTip.Content>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding [...].Tooltip}"></TextBlock>
             </ToolTip.Content>
         </ToolTip>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the tooltip code to `<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>`.
Then it works as expected.
Unfortunately in this case an empty tooltip is always displayed as an empty textbox and you need extra code to set the visiblity to collapsed for empty content.